# Rails console modifies keyboard input in terminal after an error is thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I have a bit of a strange problem.

Whenever I open up the rails console it seems to work fine until an error occurs. Then the ruby process won't stop, not even with cmd-c & cmd-z, and the keyboard gets taken over

For example, after typing in fhfh I get this returned

```
irb(main):003:0> fhfh
NameError: undefined local variable or method `fhfh' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/tristangrace/Dropbox/repos/memoryzen/memoryzen/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1^C
```

Then typing anything in the terminal gets modified.
For example holding down the left arrow returns `DD[D[D[D[D[[DDD`

I can't even get back to using the terminal. I have to open a new one. When I try to close the window it says that a ruby process is still running, and I have to force close it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using OS X; what terminal program are you using?

If it's the built-in one, go to Preferences, then Profiles, choose the one that you use, click Advanced, and make sure that terminfo is xterm-256color, and that you don't have "escape non-ASCII input with Control-V" selected.

I'd also make sure "Set locale environment variables on startup" is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I already have all of those options set.